# Beam pipeline not moving in Google Dataflow while running ok on direct runner

Tags: gradle, deployment, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, shadowjar

I have a Beam pipeline runs well locally with DirectRunner. However, when switching to the DataFlowRunner, the job started and I can see the flow chart from the Google dataflow web ui. However, the job does not run. It was hanging there till I stop the job. I am using Beam 2.10. I can see the auto scaling adjusting cpu and no exception in the log.

I think this has something to do with the way I create the Jar file. I am using the shadow Jar to create the jar file in gradle build. Main reason to use the ShadowJar is for mergeServiceFiles(). If not using mergeServiceFiles(), the job will run with exception like **No FileSystem found for gs**.

So I copied the word count from google dataflow template repo and package as jar file. It shows the same thing, the job started but not moving. The code has been touched with miniumum change for the service account credential. Instead of its original PipelineOptions, I extends the GcsOptions for the credential.

Tried beam 2.12, 2.10.

Comment: Shaded jar should work fine on Dataflow. And the fact that it autoscales is also a good sign. What do you mean by the job not running? Do you expect some output that is not there as the result of the job execution? Does the Dataflow example work if you run it not as a shaded jar? And can you message me the job IDs?

Comment: And what kind of logs do you see? Can you share them?

Comment: I am expecting the pipeline to read some input gs files and then sorting and output to output gs file. 
I think I may just found the cause of the issue. Applying fix to it. I was watching the log by the log button on the page with flow chart. Over there all looking good. However, with the 'stackdriver' small link above the logs. I found full log. First project with dataflow. So bit lost

Comment: Then found out there was app already exit out but the web ui shows running. Above it has the very common log4j and slfj binding conflict. I think that would be cause

Comment: Yes. Confirmed @Anton, after excluding the log4j from dependency, it worked fine

Comment: Glad you figured it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dig around and found the full log by clicking on the **stackdrive** on the upper right corner of the log shown. Found the following

`Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Detected both log4j-over-slf4j.jar AND bound slf4j-log4j12.jar on the class path, preempting StackOverflowError. See also http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#log4jDelegationLoop for more details. at org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory.<clinit>(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:54) ....`

Then there is a 
`java failed with exit status 1`
log entry few rows under the log4j error. Basically the java program already stopped but the dataflow UI still showing it is running on the flow chart.

Use the gradle build script to exclude all the slf4j-log4j12 from 
`compile ('org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-mapreduce-client-core:3.2.0') {exclude group: 'org.slf4j', module: 'slf4j-log4j12'}`

and other dependencies contains slf4j-log4j12 and the job start moving.

Comment: from the description this sounds like a bug, filed https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-7330